# Multiplying elements in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm supposed to multiply each element in the list `n` by 2 but for some reason it keeps returning `[6,5,7]`. For some reason its only multiplying the first element but I want it to multiply all the elements and then return the list.

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
        return x

print(double_list(n))
```

Comment: `return` stops the function. Debug with `print` statements inside the function (with and without `return`), and you'll see

Comment: @Mel it returned  [6,5,7] , [6,10,7] , [6,10,14] , but i just want the new list with the last result . Not one after another ... This is confusing me lol

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you return x after the first iteration.

You should return x after the loop ends, than you will get the requested result.

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print (double_list(n))
```

For more information about the return statemtent, you can read [here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51c0e35d7c82caace80008b1)

Answer (score 0):

you returned from inside the loop. when the first element is updated then immediately it will return without updating other ones.
you should return outside the for loop.

```
 def double_list(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]*=2
    return x

n=[24,20,48]
double_list(n)
```

it works fine for me. try it in yours 
note that your original list n changes.